# how to detect if long double is of extended precision or not at compile time

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-construction, compilation, conditional-compilation

On few systems double is same as long double.
How can I detect if long double is of extended precision than double at compile time and use it to conditional compile.

I see there are predefined macros present in libgcc **SIZEOF_DOUBLE** and **SIZEOF_LONG_DOUBLE**
But there are not portable across different toolchains.

Is there C way to do this?

Comment: You could try `sizeof(double) > 8`. Although not portable either, it'll probably still work in most cases.

Comment: Can't you test `sizeof(double) < sizeof(long double)` or am I missing something?

Comment: The preprocessor doesn't recognize `sizeof`.

Comment: Just curious, how are you going to use this information?

Comment: I'm implementing few double precision functions, to verify them I would need long double but long double is not always of extended precision. If long double is same as double I will use mpfr libray for reference.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could compare `DBL_MANT_DIG` and `LDBL_MANT_DIG` from `float.h`.

Answer (score 2):

You can test e.g.

```
#if DBL_MANT_DIG < LDBL_MANT_DIG
```

or similar values defined in float.h

Answer (score 0):

The "correct" solution to this problem (as used by many projects) is to create a configure script.

The configure script runs various tests that include compiling and running small programs to determine compiler and system properties. The script then writes out it's findings as a header file, or a makefile, or both. Of course, yours can do anything you like.

There are tools some tools to do this sort of thing semi-automatically, but they're probably overkill for you. If you'd like to take a look the names are *autoconf* and *automake*. Beware, they're not simple to learn, but they generate configure scripts and makefiles that should work on just about any platform as long as it has a unix-style shell, and GNU make.

Answer (score -1):

Why do you want `long double`? For precision. So go straight to the core of the issue and test for precision, specified by `EPSILON`:

```
#include <float.h>
printf("Info: long double epsilon = %10.4Lg\n", LDBL_EPSILON);
if (LDBL_EPSILON > 1.2e-19) {
    printf("Insufficient precision of long double type\n");
    return 1;
}
```

This is a test at run time though, not at configure or compile time.

Put it either in a unit test, or in a little test program to be run from CMake (as proposed in the [answer by ams](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8780836/1017348)).

Comment: `...at compile time` and `if (LDBL_EPSILON > 1.2e-19)` is a runtime expression and you can't compare floats at compile time (in preprocessor)./

Comment: True. I'd put it in the first unit test. Or in a test program run from CMake.

Comment: @KamilCuk Edited my answer to reflect your objection. Thanks.